# Avoid double redirect NGINX

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite

I'm redirecting my website users to the HTTPS version of the site using a 301 redirect with Nginx.
I've tested my site using PageSpeed from Google and found that I was double redirecting from the main page. This is because of my CMS. Example:
http:// domain.tld -> NGINX 301 -> to https:// domain.tld -> CMS redirect -> https:// domain.tld/homepage 

I was hoping that I could redirect the direct root link using NGINX with

```
location = / {
    return 301 https:// domain.tld/homepage;
}
```

this works for the home page, however, this will give 404 errors to any other http page than the homepage, I tried adding `return 301 https://$host$request_uri;` under the location block, but somehow this overwrites the root domain rule. (which give a double redirect again) Is there any way to redirect all links with their appropriate request_uri, EXCEPT for the root domain?

P.S. I was hoping to do this without an `if` function: See: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/

Here is a sample of my full config file:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  domainname.tld;

    location = / {
        return 301 https://domainname.tld/homepage;
    }

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri; 
    #if i remove this I'll get 404 errors on any other page than the homepage.
    #but if I add it, the 'location = /' block gets ignored.
}

server {

    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name domainname.tld;

    root /var/www/domainname.tld;
    index index.php;

    ... (stuff like rewrite rules, irrelevant) ...

}
```

Comment: Giving 404 means it redirects you to a wrong URL. What is the wrong URL that you are being redirected to?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't specify this clearly. It gives a 404 to ANY http link because http has no root folder added in the server block. I'll add this to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap it in a `location / { ... }` block to give it equal precedence:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  domainname.tld;

    location = / {
        return 301 https://$server_name/homepage;
    }
    location / {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri; 
    }
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Comment: This worked! I combined this with the 302 redirect from coladict answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to match only the root url, like this.

```
    location ~ ^/$ {
        return 301 https://domainname.tld/homepage;
    }
```

However, it is a better to keep it with a 301 code redirecting just to the HTTPS site, and a 302 code from the HTTPS site root to `/homepage`. You don't want search engines caching a 301 permanent redirect. It's a bad idea, because that page is likely to eventually change.